# Using an asset from a game as logo

Tags: copyright, is-x-legal

I am part of a relatively small [FIRST Tech Challenge](https://www.firstinspires.org/robotics/ftc) robotics team. For the past few years we have used the Redstone icon from Minecraft as our logo, but we have now decided to put a little more effort into building the team and therefore acquiring some sponsors and making some team shirts/merch(that only members of the team will wear during the competition and we will not be selling).
Are we allowed to use the redstone icon for these purposes? If not, can we use the redstone outline/colors to create a new logo that will be very similar but not directly taken from the game? Are these purposes considered "commercial use"?

Comment: actual legal advice is not for this forum.

Answer (score 1):

### Yes, if you own the copyright

You did say you created the logo, right?

### Yes, if you have permission

You got that from the copyright owner (Microsoft), right?

### Yes, if it’s [fair use](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_use)

Except … it isn’t.

Comment: The Snark is stong with this one.

Comment: Logos are protected by trademark law, not copyright law.

Comment: @nick012000 look up the image - it might be a trademark but even if it isn’t, it has copyright

Comment: If they're using it as a logo, would copyright law even apply? Trademark law applies to logos, not copyright law.

Comment: @nick012000 Yes, you can take **a lot** of things as trademark. For example, [Mozart Balls](https://trademarkblog.kluweriplaw.com/2018/01/22/austria-mozartkugeln-battlefield-local-trademark-conflicts)! there's a trademark that uses one particular painting of Mozart for their Mozart pralines, and another brand that does a very similar praline under the same name uses a different painting and labelling and such. In fact, [you can identify the manufacturer by the used image!](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mozartkugel)

Comment: @nick012000: Copyright law applies to any creative work fixed in a medium of expression, which clearly covers icons that use original artwork. Using something as a logo isn't an excuse for violating copyright. Trademark laws allow some things that aren't covered by copyright (e.g. the name "Apple") to be protected as trademarks--they don't reduce protections on things that are covered by copyright